# Mismatch in character encoding in angular and spring boot application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, spring-boot, unicode

I am on a large application, whose backend mainly comprises of Spring boot and frontend is based on Angular and this is defect is about mismatch in character encoding.

What's happening that, in one UI pages, there is a table which is fetching data from the backend, and in one of the columns of first name, a particular value is showing as: ***Firstname�012�*** and ideally it should appear like this: ***Firstnameê012ä***

I am expecting that, the response from the backend should be similar to what is showing on the screen.

I have cross-checked how does the data look in the backend and database and it turns out that it is the same what I am expecting (Firstnameê012ä).

What I have tried so far:

1. I have tried setting up `lang` tag to `en` in the index.html of the Angular part.
2. I have tried to add a div with language property to the angular component's html from where the data is loading in the UI screen.
3. I have tried to introduce and variable in the corresponding .ts file which is set to a particular language like this

```
currentLang = 'de'
```

and then can use this in the existing div of the corresponding html like this"

```
<div class ="some-class" [attr.lang] = "currentLang">
some fields
</div>
```

4. I have tried changing fonts in the corresponding scss files, incase that particular font isn't supporting the non-English words. But this didn't work out as well.

Comment: What is the encoding for the data in your db?

Comment: It is using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: When you do a console.log on your response data, is it showing up correctly?

Comment: Make sure to specify the page collation in the meta tag of the index.html like `<meta charset="UTF-8">` 
In addition to that, make sure the data arrives at the frontend unchanged, by the Response/Payload sub-tab in the Network tab of your developer console. 
Finally, `console.log` that response in several clients, (other than your own PC) Start with different browsers.

Comment: @alegria, thanks for the response. So, in my index.html, `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is already there. Also, while doing `console.log`, it is showing as Firstname�012�, where in the network tab it is showing as Firstnameê012ä

Comment: @PriyankaRao, no there is a mismatch in console.log and network tab data. You can see my below comment.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78925/charset-utf-8-still-shows-special-signs-as-question-mark can you check the accepted answer for this?

Comment: @PriyankaRao I checked the answer you mentioned above, where he asked to change the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, which I did but nothing changed for me. Also, I tried to change it to ISO-8859-15 but it didnt't work as well.